# .htaccess is not working at all

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i want to change this url

```
localhost/classAds/classInc/home.php
```

to

```
localhost/classAds/classInc/home/
```

for this i created .htacess file as follow,

```
RewriteEngine On                #Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule     ^home/?$    home.php    [NC,L]   #Handle requests for "home"
```

and put this file in

C:\wamp\www\classAds and then C:\wamp\www\classAds\classInc

but at both places it did not work,i checked Apache error log but nothing there.
actually i an new to this thing..
any idea please??

Comment: regularly the file is called ".htaccess"
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Perhaps it isn't working because you mispelled ".htaccess".

Comment: some tips:
1.Make sure your host or vhost has the AllowOverride Directive to ON
2.Make sure the apache rewrite module is installed and can be loaded properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your file .htaccess (two c's) and put it in the root folder of your website to perform the rewrite you require.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Home/ home.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^Home home.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: i just check my apache_error.log and found error something like that
   [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation, referer: http://localhost/classAds/classInc/
any idea please???

Comment: You need to check your root configuration - check out this explanation: http://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/896.html